# Python: How to append elements to a list using list iterator

Tags: list, iterator, append

Let's say we have an existing empty list, `m`. I would like to append some elements (let's say three 7's) to m so that m is now `[7,7,7]`. How to do this using list iterators?

I have the following solution, which is not complete:

```
m = []
m.append([7 for i in range(3)])
```

I get `m = [[7,7,7]]` but not `[7,7,7]`.

I am not looking for post-processing like making m flat such as:
`flat_list = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]`, because it is an extra step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try extend rather than append.

```
m = []
m.extend([7 for i in range(3)])
```

[Here is a post that may be helpful](http://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2011/03/post-2/)